# Composing streamly streams of different types

Tags: haskell, streaming, streamly

As per the [streamly tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streamly-0.2.0/docs/Streamly-Tutorial.html), it is possible to combine different streams using `<>` operator ([re-exported](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streamly-0.2.0/docs/Streamly.html#t:Semigroup) from `Semigroup` by `streamly`) like this:

```
runStream $ ((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil) <> ((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil) & S.mapM print
```

However, I'd like to combine streams which have different types, but both work with `print`. Something like this:

```
runStream $ ((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil) <> ((readLn :: IO [Char]) |: nil) & S.mapM print
```

But this gives me an error:

```
<interactive>:27:45: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: SerialT IO Int
        Actual type: SerialT IO [Char]
    • In the second argument of ‘(<>)’, namely
        ‘((readLn :: IO [Char]) |: nil)’
      In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
        ‘((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil) <> ((readLn :: IO [Char]) |: nil)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil) <> ((readLn :: IO [Char]) |: nil)
           & S.mapM print’
```

Any hints on how to do this?

---

The above code has been run in `ghci` with these are the imports:

```
import Streamly
import Streamly.Prelude ((|:), nil)
import qualified Streamly.Prelude as S
import Data.Function ((&))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `S.mapM` only works on things that are already monads, presumably you can convert them to a shared type -- say, ones containing `String`s -- then traverse the shared stream type. `print` is just `putStrLn . show`, so:

```
runStream $ (show <$> ((readLn :: IO Int) |: nil)) <> (show <$> ((readLn :: IO [Char]) |: nil)) & S.mapM putStrLn
```

Comment: That seems to work! Say the first stream had lots of elements, any idea if `show <$>` would impact the 'streaminess' of it (ie. would it start collecting results memory for some strange reason)?

Comment: @zoran119 It seems unlikely to me that `show <$> stream` would have significantly worse "streaminess" than `stream`, but take that with a grain of salt, since I have never heard of the streamly library before approximately 40 minutes ago.